# How can I get the name of the macOS startup drive within Python without using `osascript`?

Tags: python, macos

I need a Python script to know my Mac's startup drive name. This does work:

```
ascript = 'tell application "System Events" to get (name of startup disk)'
cmd = "osascript -e '{}'".format(ascript)
startup_vol = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True).splitlines()[0]
```

But seriously, Python calling a subprocess calling `osascript` calling AppleScript? Think I can squeeze any other languages in there?

Is there a native Python way to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure about a python module, but I don't see anything wrong with what you have so far.

Comment: Well, it works, just seems a long way to go about getting it. I figured there might be a more straightforward method.

Comment: Could you just look at which directory in `/Volumes/` is linked to `/`?

Comment: @Ssswift Interesting idea, I'll try that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use `pyobjc`? It should be installed by default anyway.

```
from Foundation import NSFileManager
print(NSFileManager.defaultManager().displayNameAtPath_('/'))
```

Result:

```
$ python -c "from Foundation import NSFileManager; print(NSFileManager.defaultManager().displayNameAtPath_('/'))"
Macintosh HD
```

Only for completeness sake - you can also use the python bindings to the Carbon API, although [it is deprecated and not recommended to use](https://docs.python.org/2/library/carbon.html) and the API is overall pretty clumsy:

```
$ python -c "import Carbon.File; print(Carbon.File.FSRef('/').FSGetCatalogInfo(0)[1])"
Macintosh HD
```

Comment: This sounds like it would be great, but `from Foundation import NSFileManager` results in `ImportError: No module named Foundation`, so it's not installed by default, and I'd like this to work with a default Python installation.

Comment: @Chuck What OS version do you have? [`pyobjc` is being preinstalled on Macs since Leopard](https://opensource.apple.com/source/pyobjc/pyobjc-26/pyobjc/pyobjc-website/static/downloads.rst.auto.html). It may be of an old version though. What do you get by running `python -c "import objc" `?

Comment: Or maybe you are not using the system python at all - did you install python via Homebrew or MacPorts? Issue `$ /usr/bin/python -c "from Foundation import NSFileManager"` to make sure you are testing against the system python and not some custom installation.

Comment: I tried the code in Idle, and it didn't work, but tried in the command line as you had, and it did, so it is that Idle is using a Homebrew installed version. ty.

Comment: Yeah, sadly brewed python does not share the `site-packages` with the system python, but you can always install it yourself: make sure you are using `pip` from brewed python installation, issue `pip install pyobjc-core pyobjc` and you're good to go.